# JNI, NDK, and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have recently begun using the Android NDK and I have successfully implemented a few simple Android apps. I need to detect objects (squares and rectangles) from an image. My research has shown me that OpenCV is the solution for this. [This](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp?rev=4079) is the algorithm I use to detect a square from the image.

However, I am unclear as to how should I use the squares.cpp file in my code. The OpenCV samples show how to use the cpp files in JNI format. Do I need to convert the squares.cpp file to JNI or would there be another feasible solution?

Thanks. All suggestions and feedback are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert the `squares.cpp` file to JNI.

From your Java code, you will call a JNI function (as I suppose you did in the "few simple Android apps" you have implemented) that will then call the functions in `squares.cpp`.

In other words, you basically only need one call to a JNI function from Java, and once you are in the C++ code, you can code in C++ as usual.

Comment: The link to the cpp file (provided in my question) does not have any JNI function. So do I create them manually?

Comment: Look at how the samples are made. There's basically one Java call to a C++ function using JNI. But then, inside this "JNI function", everything is C++. You can then write normal C++ in this function, and call 'squares.cpp'.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the tip. I'm working on that right now. Will let you know how it turns out soon